# How to set different culture for currency in Value Axis label Kendo ui?

Tags: kendo-ui, format, currency

I want to change the currency label in Axis Value, instead of being US dollar sign, to be Sterlling en-GB currency.

```
valueAxis: {
              labels: {
                   format: '{0:c}'
              },
```

I've already see this way

> http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization

but I'ld like to know if exists a property which I could use for the label.

The project is in AngularJs.